# App Script in google sheets doesn't work: Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to write a function in Google Sheets App Script so that I can select multiple values for a single cell in a dropdown list. The values are separated by "|" signs.

I'm trying to set up App Script in google sheets to allow a dropdown list to select multiple values for a single cell separated by a sign (in my case, that sign is "|").

The function to do this is below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var oldValue;
    var newValue;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if(activeCell.getColumn() >= 8 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1") {
        newValue = e.value;
        oldValue = e.oldValue;
        if (!e.value) {
            activeCell.setValue("");
        }
        else {
            if (!e.oldValue) {
                activeCell.setValue(newValue);
            }
            else {
                if (oldValue.indexOf(newValue) < 0) {
                    activeCell.setValue(oldValue + '|' + newValue);
                }
                else {
                    activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this script only works for column 8. For the other columns: 9, 10 , 11 etc it doesn't work. It should work for the 8th column and beyond.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try using a html dialog with a select set to multiple

Comment: Here is dummy data for an example. You need to be able to select 2 or more values in the second and third columns that are separated by "|" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u-vgFZoq4HtyeEFV2oF3Qb6ywlEQrGPWnBTMnWcP7gc/edit#gid=0

Comment: While building another table, I figured it out and solved the problem. You need to enable "show warnings" in advanced options of data validation rules. Thank you all for your participation!